# CSS circular progress, linear seconds not accurate?

Tags: c#, html, css, svg

From https://jsfiddle.net/uk9gvsao/7/, I want it to take 20 seconds to complete. Even though I have 40s in there it seems to only take around 12 seconds. I can just increase the 40s but was wondering why it wasn’t exact.

Also, I’d like a silver ring immediately created then the white ring progressively overwriting it so the user sees the expected path of the white ring. Can someone show how to do that there? Tia.

```
<div class='a1'>
    <svg height="40" width="40">
        <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="12" stroke="white" stroke-width="5" fill="black" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.a1 {
    background-color: black;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}

svg {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    stroke-dasharray: 251;
    /* (2PI * 40px) */
    stroke-dashoffset: 251;
    animation: offsettozero 40s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes offsettozero {
    to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: The circle radius is actually 12 - 5 (stroke-width) not 40.

Comment: The circle radius is  2PI * radius. In your case 2*Math.PI * 12 = 74

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adjust the `stroke-dasharray` to keep the `0` of the animation. You can also consider a small `radial-gradient` to create the bottom circle:

```css
.a1 {
  background-color: black;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

svg{
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  stroke-dasharray: 76;
  /* 12 x 3.14(PI) x 2*/
  stroke-dashoffset: 76;
  animation: offsettozero 10s linear forwards;
  
  /*bottom circle*/
  background:radial-gradient(circle at 20px 20px,
    transparent 9px,red 10px,red 14px,transparent 15px);
  /*we canget rid of [circle at 20px 20px] since it's the center by default*/
}

@keyframes offsettozero {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='a1'>
  <svg height="40" width="40">
     <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="12" stroke="white" stroke-width="5" fill="transparent" />
   </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I’m trying to figure out how to get your red stroke width the same as the white stroke width.

Comment: @user1946932 check the update, you need a transparen fill for the circle

Answer (score 2):

You need to adjust the value of `stroke-dashoffset` at last keyframe

```
@keyframes offsettozero {
   to {
      stroke-dashoffset: 176;
   }
}
```

Visually you can't see any difference between `0` and `176` but in the first case the animation is still running exceeding the value needed.

To better understand you can try to set the value to `175` and see how the animation works.

> [Jsfiddle fork](https://jsfiddle.net/v8x2gwnr/)

Answer (score 1):

So, as pointed by @fcalderan the time interval needs to be 176, also we duplicate the svg's and position them one on top of the other. The background one serves as the guide and the top one is the animated one.

So your code will change into this:

```
<div class='a1'>
<svg height="40" width="40" class="bg">
    <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="12" stroke="rgba(99, 99, 99, 0.5)" stroke-width="5" fill="black" />
</svg>  
<svg height="40" width="40" class="first">
    <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="12" stroke="white" stroke-width="5" fill="black" />
</svg>
```

...and CSS...

```
.a1 {
    background-color: black;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}

.a1 svg {
    position: absolute;
}

.first {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    stroke-dasharray: 251;
    /* (2PI * 40px) */
    stroke-dashoffset: 251;
    animation: offsettozero 176s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes offsettozero {
    to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}
```